# How to manage an array of objects and make them each one generate a thread?

Tags: java, arrays, multithreading

I have created a Pool of Threads in an array and I want each object contained in this array to generate a thread, that basically makes a movement.  Each object should be moved in a different direction but instead they all move to the same direction. 
I got this so far :

```
  for (int i=0; i<network.mobiles.size(); i++) {
           final int j = i ;
        threadPool.submit(new Runnable() {

             public void run() {

                 int value = 10 ;

                 for (int z=0; z<value; z++){
                     value++;
                     int x = mobnod[j].getLocationOnScreen().x;
                     int y = mobnod[j].getLocationOnScreen().y;
                     double r = Math.random();
                     if      (r < 0.25) mobnod[j].getLocationOnScreen().x--;
                     else if (r < 0.50) mobnod[j].getLocationOnScreen().x++;
                     else if (r < 0.75) mobnod[j].getLocationOnScreen().y--;
                     else if (r < 1.00) mobnod[j].getLocationOnScreen().y++;

                     mobnod[j].setLocation(x, y);
                     network.mobiles.get(j).findClosestAP(network.nodes);
                     network.setConnections();
                    try {
                        threadPool.awaitTermination(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
             }

         });
     }
     // once you've submitted your last job to the service it should be shut down
     threadPool.shutdown();
     // wait for the threads to finish if necessary


}
```

Could you help me please ?

Comment: Could you post the complete program so we could try running it. Also your for loop seems like an infinite loop, is that intended?

Answer (score 0):

You store the item's location in local x and y variables, then you use a random number to change the item's location, but then you set the item's location back to the original x and y that you stored locally.  Perhaps that's the problem?